# How to change a mouseover event to a onclick one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I want. There are many words such as test1, test2, test3, ... And each of them is associated with one or more examples. I want to show the words side by side, and have the examples show when the associated word is "clicked" At first, I wrote like below (mouseover event), but I realized it doesn't work in mobile environments. So I need to change my plan. I want the action to occur when the user clicks the word.

https://jsfiddle.net/kyubyong/umxf19vo/

HTML

```
<a>test1</a>
<div class="divs">
    <li>This is the example of test1</li>
</div>

<a>test2</a>
<div class="divs">
    <li>This is the example of test3</li>
</div>

<a>test3></a>
<div class="divs">
    <li>This is the example of test3</li>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a:hover
{
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.divs 
{
  display: none;
}

a:hover + .divs 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You have no JavaScript so there isn't a `mouseover` event.

Comment: Add an onclick attribute to the elements `<b onclick="">test2</b></a>` or a click handler

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the event you're after is the `click` event.

I don't think this can be done using only css like in your jsfiddle example, but it certainly can be done with javascript.

This is one way to approach it using jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
 $('a').removeClass('active');
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

See the working example on https://jsfiddle.net/fznL3c9L/

Comment: Thanks. I've searched for a javascript way in Google for hours, but nothing was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JavaScript Hide/Show System.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return show1()">test1</a>
<div id="show1" style="display:none">
    //display info
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function show1() {
    document.getElementById("show1").style.display="block";
    return false;
}
```

and then use the Div CSS you have already, that should work for you pretty well, if you want to hide it you will either have to have another button or a more complex if statement.

Comment: Please cancel the onclick too and do try not to have inline JS

Comment: @mplungjan Edited, reply if you see any other problems in it. Thank You!

Comment: Also, If you want to go fancy you can change the link `<a href="#" onClick=show1()">` to a button element keeping the onClick attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

You cannot achive this by CSS alone. So I tried adding some jQuery.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $(this).next('div').toggleClass("testClass");
    });
})
```

CSS:

```
.testClass
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/umxf19vo/19/)

**OR**

HTML:

```
<a onClick="showDivs(this)">
```

jQuery:

```
function showDivs(currentElem){
    $(currentElem).next('div').toggleClass("testClass");
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for the tip. Updated the code using 'toggleClass'

Answer (score 0):

HAHAHAHA

```js
var i = $("nav > ul > li").length;
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            a(j);
        };
        function a (j) {
            $('nav > ul > li').eq(j%i).click(function() {
                $('nav > ul > li > ul').eq(j%i).css('display', 'block');
            });
            $('nav > ul > li').eq(j%i).mouseout(function() {
                $('nav > ul > li > ul').eq(j%i).css('display', 'none');
            });
        }
```

```css
nav > ul > li{
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    nav > ul > li > ul{
        padding: 0;
        display: none;
    }
    li{
        display: block;
    }
    nav > ul > li:hover{
        background-color: #ffff00;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>nav1
            <ul>
                <li>aaa1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>nav2
            <ul>
                <li>bbb1</li>
                <li>bbb2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>nav3
            <ul>
                <li>ccc1</li>
                <li>ccc2</li>
                <li>ccc3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>nav4
            <ul>
                <li>ddd1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```